# Xamarin fixed navigation bar

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I have a fixed footer like Instagram through multiple pages in a xamarin forms app without determining it on every page?

I find out I can use a nuget package to make this like a tapped page but it makes me write all the codes in one page like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp_2F621Az0

how can I implement this more efficiently

Comment: Read about `TabbedPage` from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59914/is-it-possible-to-add-a-footer-to-all-the-content-page-in-xamrin-forms

Answer (score 1):

In this cenario I suggest you use Tabbed Page. Because the tabs will are part down in your app.

In this link you can read and understand how works a tabbed page:
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/